# jQuery - trim the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following example:

`var VarFull = $('#selectror').attr('href')` where `.attr('href') = "#tabs1-1"`

How can I trim that to `"tabs1-1"` ( without `#`)??

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Added the `javascript` tag. This is much more a JavaScript than a jQuery question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`substring`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.15):

```
var VarFull = $('#selectror').attr('href').substring(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript's string `replace()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
var VarFull = $('#selectror').attr('href');
var trimmed = VarFull.replace('#','');
```

**Edit:**
This is a good article on JS string manipulation: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace` -

```
var VarFull = $('#selectror').attr('href').replace('#','');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this regEx with replace-

```
var VarFull = $('#selectror').attr('href').replace(/\#*/g, "");
```

it will replace all the # in your attr.

Comment: Why complicate the `replace()` by passing in regex? Won't the simpler `replace('#','')` work?

Comment: yes it work...but i have given it, if in some case he want to replace all `#`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's certain that the url will contain # anyway, you can even split and take second element of array.

```
var trimmed=$('#selectror').attr('href').split("#")[1]
```

But don't use this if URL may not contain # otherwise you'll get an undefined error for trying to get index 1 of the array by split().

Comment: This is very simple and usefull method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For example: "`. / email@gmail.com, / . \`"

Now `trim` characters at the beginning and end of the string:

```
email_new = email.replace(/\W+$/g, '').replace(/^\W+/g, ''); // output : email@gmail.com
```